# Regex between " but not beyond

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to use a regex to capture everything between `"` (including the `"` itself)
The problem is this:

Regex:

```
\\\"(.[^,][^\\\"]*)\\\"
```

Text:

```
"text", text2, "text"
    meeeh = "Y"
else
    meeeh2 = "N"
```

with this regex, the folling is selected:

```
"text"    "text"
         "Y"
else
    meeeh2 = "
```

The problem seems to be that the regex doesn't stop when nothing is behind the `"` or when there is a newline.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about this `\"(.*?)\"`  or `(\".*?\")` regex? see http://regex101.com/r/cA4wE0/9

Comment: @Alovchin Why you deleted your answer?

Comment: @Alovchin a small gift for you http://ideone.com/cMleOV :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.*?(\".*?\").*?
```

Try this.Please have a look at the demo.

http://regex101.com/r/cA4wE0/7

Comment: have a habbit of using pattern.match(string).groups() in python.So i need to match the whole string .Though its not needed here :)

Answer (score 1):

When it reaches the first `"` in `"Y"`, this is what the regex does:

- `\"` matches `"`
- `.` matches `Y`
- `[^,]` matches `"`
- `[^\"]*` matches `else    meeeh2 =`
- `\"` matches `"`

Essentially you're looking for "Any character, then anything that's not a comma, then anything but double quotes until the end" between the quotes. This means at least 2 characters, but `Y` is only 1.

If you mean *anything but quotes* between quotes, use `\"([^"]*)\"`. If you mean *anything but quotes and commas*, `\"([^",]*)\"` should do.